# Change class polymer 2.0

Tags: polymer-2.x

I am beginning to learn Polymer 2.0 and I am interested in learning ES6.  My question is what is the way to transform this in polymer 2.0? I am just learning english. 
Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.aspfilename=tryjsref_element_classname.

Comment: could you provide a little more information on what are you trying to archive?
PS: link seems to be broken...

Comment: i try to change the style of one element, i try to use documentbyID but no function and maybe you know other way to toggle the style in the element..thank youu, sorry the link is broken now!

Answer (score 0):

For selecting an element inside the "light" DOM you can just us plain javascript

```js
var el = document.getElementById('something');
console.log('Selected Element:', el);
```

```html
<div id="something">some stuff</div>
```

For selection inside your polymer 2 shadow DOM you can use
`this.$.something` or for more complex queries `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('div > p:first-child')`